# Merge misaligned pandas dataframes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have around 100 csv files. Each of them are written in to its own pandas dataframe and then merged later on and finally being written in to a database.

Each csv file contains a 1000 rows and 816 columns.

Here is the problem:

Each of the csv files contains the 816 columns but not all of the columns contains data. As a result of this some of the csv files are misaligned - the data has been moved left, but the column has not been deleted.

Here's an made up example:

CSV file A (which is correct):

```
    Name    Age City
    Joe     18  London
    Kate    19  Berlin
    Math    20  Paris
```

CSV file B (with misaglignment):

```
    Name    Age    City
    Joe     18     London
    Kate    Berlin
    Math    20     Paris
```

I would like to merge A and B, but my current solution results in a misalignment.

I'm not sure whether this is easier to deal with in SQL or Python, but I hoped some of you could come up with a good solution.

The current solution to merge the dataframes is as follows:

```
def merge_pandas(csvpaths):
    list = []
    for path in csvpaths:
        frame = pd.read_csv(sMainPath + path, header=0, index_col = None)
        list.append(frame)
    return pd.concat(list)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, can you show what the csv files look like? Because you shouldn't have this shift in individual rows, unless you screw up big time with your commas (or other separator)

Comment: Your function to merge the different frames is perfectly fine! The misalignment is a problem in the read_csv or in your csv file itself

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my question. I know it is a problem in the csv files. If I'm not completely wrong all rows should contain the same number of seperators (commas), but they doesn't. I'm looking for a way to fix this. The CSV files are downloaded from an external website, so there is not much I can do with the csv files themselves.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct delimiter when reading the data? The reason we keep asking is that a change in `read_csv` is quick and takes few seconds, an ex-post fix by "guessing" the type of variable and hence the column the variable belongs to is several orders of magnitude more complex.

Comment: @FooBar: Thanks for your commment. Yes, I'm sure I'm using the correct delimiter. I have most recently taking over this project, and the guy before me corrected all the misalignments in excel, and there is no way I would do that. I know it's a complex problem, but I'm looking for someone to guide me to the most feasible solution, since I have no clue how to deal with such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solutions for these types of problems is most likely overkill. We note that the only possible mistake is when a value is written into a column *to the left* from where it belongs.

If your problem is more complex than the two column example you gave, you should have an array that contains the expected column type for your convenience.

```
types = ['string', 'int']
```

Next, I would set up a marker to identify flaws:

```
df['error'] = 0
df.loc[df.City.isnull(), 'error'] = 1
```

**The script can detect the error with certainty**

In your simple scenario, whenever there is an error, we can simply check the value in the first column.

- If it's a number, ignore and move on (keep `NaN` on second value)
- If it's a string, move it to the right

In your trivial example, that would be

```
def checkRow(row):
    try:
        row['Age'] = int(row['Age'])
    except ValueError:
        row['City']= row['Age']
        row['Age'] = np.NaN
    return row

df.apply(checkRow, axis=1)
```

In case you have more than two columns, use your `types` variable to do iterated checks to find out where the `NaN` belongs.

**The script cannot know the error with certainty**

For example, if two adjacent columns are both string value. In that case, you're screwed. Use a second marker to save these columns and do it manually. You could of course do advanced checks (it should be a city name, check whether the value is a city name), but this is probably overkill and doing it manually is faster.

Comment: Thanks - this was the kind of answer I was looking for!